# Dependency Injection Azure function custom object for request

Tags: azure, logging, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have Iot Hub where multiple IoT devices are connected. I have IoT Hub trigger Azure function which refer to different class libraries for data processing and other work.

I am trying to do logging for what is happening when data receive from devices and any error while processing etc. So different information, warning and error logs are there.
In addition to that I have some durable functions which gets invoked parallely.

When I write log statement, I want Deviceid to get appended as prefix to each log statement. This is to track the for which device we got error, warning etc.

Is there any way, If I create customer logger object, set the device id when we get the data and then inject that object as DI (Constructor not as parameter all methods) so that other classes can use same object to log.

Comment: For logging, you can use BeingScope. For request telemetry, you can look for ITelemetryInitializer. For object DI, you can inject as scope lifetime an which can be resolved using HttpContext.

Comment: Is this BeginScope is can be used for durable function invocations? Does the scope gets carried forward to invoked durable functions ? or any class library function invoked?

Comment: The Begin scope will be carried for any method invocation of any class library Check [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3). But the scope will not be carried for invoked Orchestrator function and from to Activity function. You can add the Begin Scope on those functions too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but take a look on Custom Bindings, it can give you some ideas on how to do what you're trying:

https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip247.html